# Retrieve information in a file

Tags: windows, image, file, dataset, mediametadataretriever

Good morning. I have downloaded the Yahoo Flickr Creative Commons 100M (14G) Dataset from the official website. When i extracted it i got a 48 GB file wiithout extension. I also have a file .txt where it explains how the dataset is composed and it says that is formed with a lot of record: for any image are registered some information like the link to download, Photo/video identifier,Photo/video hash,User nickname, Date taken and other fields.
Now, i only need the images and the associated hash, so the question is: how do i get it? I have litteraly no idea. Thank you everyone for the help

> Blockquote

EDIT: I have managed to open the file with Word, but not all of it because is too big and i have over 10000 record like this, for example:

0   6985418911  4e2f7a26a1dfbf165a7e30bdabf7e72a    39089491@N00    nino63004   2012-02-16 09:56:37.0   1331840483  Canon+PowerShot+ELPH+310+HS IMG_0520        canon,canon+powershot+hs+310,carnival+escatay,cruise,elph,hs+310,key+west+florida,powershot     -81.804885  24.550558   12  (link to flickr that i can't post)  (other link)    Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivs License  (other link)    7205    8   df7747990d  692d7e0a7f  jpg 0

> Blockquote

Comment: What do you need to know?  You say you've got the download URL and the hash, what else do you need?

Comment: I have over 10000 records with information and i have to obtain only the link and hash.

Comment: From your latest edit, it sounds as if you are trying to process the file with existing software.  That makes the question off-topic here, you could try Super User I guess.  If you are trying to write your own code to process the file (which is how it is meant to be used) then please show what you have already tried along with a clear description of what goes wrong.  (FWIW, importing the file into Excel would be more sensible than opening it in Word, though I doubt Excel will be able to process the entire dataset.)

Comment: I tried with excel, i didn't fought of that, but it couldn't open it. I try to use existing software because i don't know how i could write some code to retrieve the information i need.

Comment: You could try Super User or Software Recommendations.  But I'm doubtful that there is any existing software that will process a file that size; there's no call for it.

Comment: I'll try, thank you anyway